# PHP select MySQL not inserting detailed error message as expected

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've hit a problem with php script that I'm trying out. When I start it up the script connects to MySQL and the database perfectly, but when I try and select data from the 'codes' database then it gives me an error like this:

> Could not get data:

How can I make it say

> Could not get data: (then the error here)

instead?

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";

   $sql = 'SELECT code FROM codes';
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      echo "Code:{$row['code']}";
   }

   echo "Fetched data successfully\n";

   mysql_close($conn);  
?>
```

Comment: You are combining `mysql` & `mysqli`. Use `mysqi` only in every operation

Comment: You're mixing mysqli with mysql

Comment: You Check Your Database Name .

Comment: You fully Use Mysql or Mysqli

Comment: Thanks I've switched everything that was mysql and switched it to mysqli. But it is still giving me an error without a explanation

Comment: If you have a different question, ask a different question. Or edit the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed both mysql and mysqli together so i fixed error:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "table";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
        mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// echo "Connected successfully";

   $sql = 'SELECT username FROM users';
   $retval = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql);

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
   }

   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($retval,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      echo "Code:{$row['username']}";
   }

   echo "Fetched data successfully\n";

   mysqli_close($conn);  
?>
```